# D3 geoJson map with semantic zooming

Tags: javascript, d3.js

There are many circles of different radius, text, and rectangles on the map.

On Zoom all dots are getting zoomed.

How can I exclude dots and text nodes from zoom?

From different links I found that I can scale those circle to original size by doing something like this:

```
d3.selectAll("mycircle").attr("r", 5 / d3.event.transform.k);
```

But is this the right way? Because there are so many different sizes circle, text, and rectangles on my map.

[image]

Comment: not all elements are getting scaled....only the parent element getting scaled. Anyways why would scale(0) work? Scale 0 is like u can't see the element.

Comment: If only the parent element is scaled then just add a function to the `r` and select each circle using `this` and change accordingly. `d3.selectAll(".mycircle").attr("r", function(d) { return d3.select(this).attr("r")/d3.event.transform.k;});`

Comment: Yeah, that's what I mentioned in the question. Seems like a hack. I have to do with circles, rect, text etc...

Comment: In my opinion, that would be the only solution since the parent itself gets scaled.

Comment: yeah... maybe I should try zooming each element and don't scale excluded element rather only translate them, semantic zooming is what I need.